# get param value from tag <> using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, search, tags, substring

Please help me with regular expressions in this task:
I have string:

```
<tag title = "DESIRED_DATA">
```

and I want to get the data DESIRED_DATA (using Javascript)

variants:

```
<tag SPACES PARAM_NAME#1 = PARAM_VALUE#1 title = "DESIRED_DATA" PARAM_NAME#N = PARAM_VALUES#N>

<tag SPACES title='DESIRED_DATA' SPACES>
```

etc

component of my string:

begin: `<tag`

end: `>`

title value in "" or ''

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is notoriously difficult... why not convert the HTML strings into JS DOM objects and then extract the data that way?

Comment: Is this code running in a browser or on the server (node.js)?

Answer (score -1):

Edit 2: take into account regular expressions are not the best tool for dealing with HTML. If you have access to the DOM element, you can easily access its attributes [using jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [raw DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes).

Answering your question:
If you have `'<tag title = "DESIRED_DATA">'` as a string, you can use:

```
var string = '<tag title = "DESIRED_DATA">';
var matches = string.match(/title\s*=\s*"(\w+)"/);
var data = matches[1];
```

Read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) on regular expresions for a better understanding.

Edit:
If the use of single/double quotes is consistent in the string and nested strings don't go deeper than you describe, you can use:

```
var string = '<tag param = \'title = "xxx"\' title = \'correct title\' param2 = \'trash\'>';
var lastSingleQuote = string.lastIndexOf('\'');
var lastDoubleQuote = string.lastIndexOf('"');
var pattern = lastSingleQuote > lastDoubleQuote
    ? /title\s*=\s*'([^']*)'/ 
    : /title\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"/
var matches = string.match(pattern);
var data = matches[1];
```

I also took @Makyen's suggestion into account.

Comment: While `\w+` will work for the example data, the possible valid contents contains considerably more characters than `\w` matches. You would be best off using a negated character set (i.e. match all characters except a specific list; e.g. `[^"]*`).

Comment: @GMunguia, your code don't work if

    <tag param = 'title = "xxx"' title = 'correct title' param2 = 'trash'>

Comment: Please don't recommend regex for working with HTML. This is not good advice. Regex are incapable of dealing with HTML and giving code samples that seem to indicate otherwise encourages people to keep using the worst possible tool for the job, which is at the very least counter-productive.

Comment: @Tomalak: I did not recomend it. The question was about regexp, so I answered to it. I'll edit my answer to make sure whoever reads it is aware that this is not the best tool for the job.

Comment: It's a matter of principle. Just because the user asks *"I want to do A with B"* is not enough reason to show them a way to do it with B, especially if B is the worst way of doing it. After all, what the user wants to do is A. *How* they end up doing it is irrelevant - most of the time they simply ask about B because they don't know any better. (That's certainly the case here.)